# Finding a function to a given sequence with stipulated conditions

Tags: real-analysis

Given the sequence $(x_k, y_k)=1+\frac{1}{k}, \frac{(k+1)^3}{k^2+1}$. Give to every of these points an example and show, that your example complies the stipulated conditions.

(i) A non-constant function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow 1}f(x_k,y_k)=42$

(ii) A function $\vec{g} : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, so that $\vec{g} (x_k,y_k)$ is a divergent sequence.

To (i) Since the value of both sequences is $2$ for $k \rightarrow 1$ i think  $f(x_k,y_k)=5.25xy$ fulfils the condition

(ii) Since $y_k$ diverges: $\vec{g} : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y) \mapsto [\sin(x),\cos(y)]^T$

Since $\cos(y) \in [-1,1] \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\cos(y)=\begin{cases}0&\text{k }\\1&\text{k=4n}\\ -1 &\text{k=4n+2}\end{cases}$ for $y = \frac{k\pi}{2}$ it's always possible to find a sufficiently small $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $ so that $\cos(y)\neq cos(\lambda y)$.

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part, as $k\to 1$, $(x_k,y_k)\to(2,4)$, not $(2,2)$; in particular, this part is not quite correct (see if you can modify it appropriately).

For the second part: your solution seems to be correct, but it still requires an argument. A divergent sequence input into a continuous function is not necessarily still divergent (take for example, $a_n=n$ and $f(x)=1/x$...$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ while $f(a_n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Is my solution  now correct?

Comment: @fear: looks correct!